# I'm looking for a recent comic series about a pink hair girl and set in the desert

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm trying find a fantasy comic series about a pink haired girl where she fights monsters and stuff. I think it's set in a desert.

I didn't get a chance to read it, but it's really recent; somewhere in the 2020s I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found it! It's [*Jonna and the Unpossible Monsters*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/50891304-jonna-and-the-unpossible-monsters-vol-1).

[image: Jonna and the Unpossible Monsters]

> An epic tale of sisters, survival, and some monster-punching

Rainbow has been looking for her younger sister, Jonna, for over a year--since the monsters appeared and their world began to dry up. Going from settlement to settlement, Rainbow asks every survivor she meets: Have you seen my sister?

Comment: You might want to add more information in case the link goes dead, like on one of your other answer where the Youtube video no longer works.